# "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined" error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The code gives me this "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined" error although when I console.log it it gives me the object

```
import React from "react";

class Random extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      breweries: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://api.openbrewerydb.org/breweries")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        this.setState({
          breweries: data,
        })
      })
  }

  render() {
    const brewery = this.state.breweries[Math.floor(Math.random()*this.state.breweries.length)];
    return(
      <div>{brewery.name}</div>
    )
  }
}

export default Random;
```

Comment: when you console log what `brewery.name` or just `brewery`?

Comment: when i console log only brewery

Comment: do you get this in your console: `[ ]` then `[...your data]` ? so do two things log to the console?

Comment: no, I just get the object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until the async request finishes,

```
this.state.breweries[Math.floor(Math.random()*this.state.breweries.length)]
```

will actually return `undefined`, since

```
Math.floor(Math.random()*this.state.breweries.length)
```

will return `0`, and since `this.state.breweries` is an empty array, it will return `undefined`

(`[][0]` -> `undefined`).

---

You have to secure the possibility that `brewery` is yet undefined, e.g.:

```
<div>{brewery && brewery.name}</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches to this issue.

**Approach 1: `UNSAFE_componentWillMount()`**

You could use `UNSAFE_componentWillMount()` instead of `componentDidMount()`. `UNSAFE_componentWillMount()` executes before the component is rendered so you will have the data in the state before the content is rendered. This should get rid of the error.

**Approach 2: Verifying the State is `!Empty`**

In your `render` method, you can add an `if` statement that says `breweries` is `null` if there is no data in state else breweries equals `this.state.breweries[Math.floor(Math.random()*this.state.breweries.length)]`.

Something like this:

```
render() {
    const { breweries } = this.state;
    let brewery; 
    if (breweries.length === 0){
       brewery = null;
    } else {
      brewery= 
   this.state.breweries[Math.floor(Math.random()*this.state.breweries.length)];
    }
    return(
      <div>{brewery.name}</div>
    )
  }
```

For extra insurance, you can combine the two approaches. If you did that your component would look like this:

```
import React from "react";

class Random extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      breweries: []
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    fetch("https://api.openbrewerydb.org/breweries")
      .then(response =>{ return response.json() })
      .then((data) => {
        this.setState({
          breweries: data,
        })
      })
  }

  render() {
    const { breweries } = this.state;
        let brewery; 
        if (breweries.length === 0){
           brewery = null;
        } else {
          brewery= 
       this.state.breweries[Math.floor(Math.random()*this.state.breweries.length)];
        }
    return(
      <div>{brewery.name}</div>
    )
  }
}

export default Random;
```

That should do it. Hope this helps.

**Edit: WARNING**

I wrote willMount() but it should be UNSAFE_componentWillMount(). `componentWillMount()` will not work after version 17. `UNSAFE_componentWillMount()` will work after version 17. Sorry about that. I forgot to write unsafe.

Comment: This is a harmful answer. I wouldn't suggest using `componentWillMount` to anyone.

Comment: there's noting wrong with `componentWillMount`. Unsafe will work through version 17. Personally, it's not the route I would go. I would pass this data down as a prop or use redux. But for the owner's circumstance `unsafe...willmount` is fine. I included another approach as well in case the owner was not comfortable with using an unsafe lifecycle method

Answer (score 0):

You should ensure you've fetched the data, before attempting to access an index of the array. Your random math will evaluate to `0` when the array is empty, resulting in `undefined`

```
import React from "react";

class Random extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      breweries: null
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://api.openbrewerydb.org/breweries")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        this.setState({
          breweries: data,
        })
      })
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.breweries) {
      const brewery = this.state.breweries[Math.floor(Math.random()*this.state.breweries.length)];
      return(
        <div>{brewery.name}</div>
      )
    }

    return null
  }
}

export default Random;
```

Comment: I don't understand what you've changed in his code or is this for reference purposes?